# animation-list not working in Android 5.0 (Lollipop)

Tags: android, animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I needed a simple animation which shows 3-dots loading. So I created 3 images, added it to animation list and set it to imageview. It was working fine till kitkat but after updating my OS to Lollipop, the animation doesn't seem to work.

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/one_dot"
    android:duration="500"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/two_dot"
    android:duration="500"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/three_dot"
    android:duration="500"/>

</animation-list>
```

This is how its set to the imageView

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dotsLoadingView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/loadingText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dots_loading" />
```

Is there some change regarding animation in Android 5.0 Lollipop?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) for AnimationDrawable,

> The simplest way to create a frame-by-frame animation is to define the animation in an XML file, placed in the `res/drawable/` folder, and set it as the background to a `View` object. Then, call `start()` to run the animation.

You need to call `start()` to run the animation.

```
final ImageView myView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dotsLoadingView);
((Animatable) myView.getDrawable()).start();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This seems to be the solution. But I'm still curious why I didn't have to start the animation explicitly till Kitkat version?

Comment: There was a bug in `AnimationDrawable` where changing visibility would always start an animation. This wasn't really noticeable until we started using `AnimationDrawable` for things that weren't progress spinners, e.g. the check box and radio button animations in the Material theme.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I always assumed its a feature :)

Comment: @alanv do you happen to have the link to the issue ticket about this?

Comment: There is no public issue ticket.